# Numerical problems with calculation of function

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I have a problem with a calculation which I try to do with Mathematica (8.0.1).

I have the following function which describes a cone (with half opening angle `theta`) which can be tilted (with the angles `thetaTilt` and `phiTilt`) around its base point `lG`. For some unimportant reasons the tip of this cone (if not tilted) is at the position `–rout/Tan[theta]`. So, `rout` describes in the following function the diameter of the cone tip at the position `z=0` (again for the not tilted case):

```
coneFunction[x_, y_, theta_, thetaTilt_, phiTilt_, lG_, rout_] := 
1/(Cos[2 theta] - 
Cos[2 thetaTilt]) (rout Cos[thetaTilt] Sin[2 theta] + 
 2 lG (1 + Cos[2 theta] + 2 Cos[thetaTilt]) Sin[thetaTilt/
   2]^2 - \[Sqrt](Cos[theta]^2 (lG^2 + x^2 + y^2 + 
      rout Cot[theta] (2 lG + rout Cot[theta]) +  2 x y Sin[2 phiTilt] + 
      Cos[2 thetaTilt] (-lG^2 + x^2 + y^2 -  rout Cot[theta]
 (2 lG + rout Cot[theta]) -  2 x y Sin[2 phiTilt]) + 
      8 (x Cos[phiTilt] + y Sin[phiTilt]) Sin[theta] (rout Cos[theta] +
lG Sin[theta]) Sin[thetaTilt] + 
      2 (x - y) (x + y) Cos[2 phiTilt] Sin[thetaTilt]^2 + 
      Cos[2 theta] (-lG^2 - 2 (x^2 + y^2) + 
         lG^2 Cos[2 thetaTilt] - 2 rout Cot[theta] (2 lG + rout Cot[theta])
 Sin[thetaTilt]^2))) + (x Cos[phiTilt] + y Sin[phiTilt]) Sin[2 thetaTilt]);
```

Since it is difficult to understand what this function does (and what I mean in my text), I suggest that one plots an cross-section of this function, e.g. with

```
theta=3.5*10^-3;(*half opening angle of cone in rad*)
rout=0.65*10^-6;(*diameter at tip of cone*)
lG=10*10^-3;(*basepoint of the cone*)
Plot[coneFunction[x, 0, theta, 0, 0, lG, rout], 
{x, -0.000005,0.000005}, 
PlotRange -> {1.2*{-0.000005, 0.000005}, {-0.0002, 0.001}}, 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 120]
```

[image: cross section of cone]

Or a 3D plot with e.g.:

```
thetaTilt = 0;
phiTilt = 0;
Show[Plot3D[{coneFunction[x, y, theta, thetaTilt, phiTilt, lG, rout]}, 
{x, -0.001, 0.001}, {y, -0.001, 0.001}, 
Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 60, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.4], Gray]],
Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x/m", "y/m", "z/m"}, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {{-0.0001, 0.0001}, {-0.0001, 0.0001}, {-0.001, 0.012}}]
```

[image: 3D plot of cone]

If one sets `thetaTilt` to small values such as 10^-4, it can be seen easily, that the cone is being tilted by this value.

If the cone is not tilted, the function is independent of `lG`. This can be seen easily by:

```
Simplify[coneFunction[x, y, theta, 0, 0, lG, rout]]
```

So, regardless what x or y values I chose, I should get back always the same result for different values of the base point `lG`.

But that is not the case!
If I use e.g.

```
testTable = 
Table[SetPrecision[
coneFunction[-0.000005, 0, theta, 0, 0, lG, rout], 10], 
{lG, 0.0053, 0.0055, 0.0000001}];
```

I get as output most time 0.001242850670, but also some other values (e.g. 0.001242846719). So, if I have bad luck and chose a “bad” `lG` value, I would get back wrong results.

I assume that this has something to do with the numeric of Mathematica. I tried to get rid of this effect with some attempts (e.g. `SetPrecision`, `Rationalize`, `Evaluate`), but none of them worked.

So, who can give me some advice? How can I manage that my function gives back for all `lG` the right result (also for the tilted case)?

Since I am clueless I would appreciate any support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the current setup you get three different answers:

```
testTable // Union

(* ==> {0.001242846719, 0.001242850670, 0.001242854621} *)
```

The problem is that you haven't sufficiently increased the precision of all numbers, including those in the loop bounds.

```
theta = SetPrecision[3.5*10^-3, 50];
rout = SetPrecision[0.65*10^-6, 50];

testTable = 
  Table[
    SetPrecision[
      coneFunction[-0.000005`50, 0, theta, 0, 0, lG, rout], 
      10
    ], 
    {lG, 0.0053`50, 0.0055`50, 0.0000001`50}
  ];

testTable // Union

(* ==>  {0.001242852068} *)
```

The following might also be worth to note:

```
SetPrecision[Sin[1000], 10] // Precision

(* ==> 7.167413092 *)
```

The expression is evaluated  with 10 digits of precision, but the `Sin` operation loses quite some precision.

Comment: If you're evaluating trigonometric functions at values that are quite large, you are probably doing something wrong...

Comment: Thanks @Sjoerd for editing and for almost answering my question! You gave me also some useful info (I wasn’t aware that `Sin` etc. loses precision. Do you know why?).
I also found an own “almost solution”. I define my values e.g. `theta=3.5*10^-3` etc. and then I define `coneFunction[]:=Evaluate[Simplify[Formula]]`. Then I also get back just one value: 0.001242852152. Interestingly, this value is different to your value. If I read back e.g. theta, I get 0.003500000000000000072... Could it be that these odd non-zero numbers cause this discrepancy? Simply asked: What is the true result?